# Fixed Tabs in the same view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new in Android. I wanna create an application that shows an action bar with fixed tabs. I've reached to do this. 
The problem is that the tabs don`t fit in the same view.

This is my Main Activity:

```
 package com.pestana.pestana;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable
    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3,Tab4;
    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();
    Fragment fragmentTab4 = new FragmentTab4();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
        Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3");
        Tab4 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab4");

        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));
        Tab4.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab4));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab4);
    }

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true; /** true -> el menú ya está visible */
     }
}
```

And this is the layout

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

`

I've created also 4 classes for FragmentTab1... FragmentTab4,

FragmentTab1

```
    package com.pestana.pestana;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

FragmentTab2

```
    package com.pestana.pestana;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

FragmentTab3

```
    package com.pestana.pestana;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentTab3 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

FragmentTab4

```
    package com.pestana.pestana;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentTab4 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab4, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

TabListener.java

```
    package com.pestana.pestana;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    Fragment fragment;

    public TabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

4 XML layout for each fragment this is an example, just have to change Fragment1 for each XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Fragment1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am stuck for 3 days, any help please?? With the same code can I implement a swipe view with the different tabs?? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by this `The problem is that the tabs don\`t fit in the same view` ?

Comment: If you want to implement the Swipe view with different tabs then you can go for `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation ([Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)), you can download a working example of how to do exactly what you want.